# How to continue a series in a Excel table when adding new rows

Tags: excel, newrow

I have a table in which a column contains weekdays, which are increased by one at each new row. Is there a way to make this automatic? I mean when I start typing new data to a new row, it automatically fills the weekday column following the series.

Comment: can you show us any example?